# Kubuntu Cannot Update

Tags: kubuntu, update-manager, muon-package-manager

I tried updating Kubuntu using Muon Update Manager which failed to apply changes.

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/project-neon5
kio_0.0+git20141008.0321+neon4~faa423d~14.04_amd64.deb 
trying to overwrite '/opt/project-neon5/bin/ktrash5', which is also in package
project-neon5-kio-extras 0.0+git20140928.0353+neon4~90b5683~14.04
```

Comment: Is it possible to format or clarify the information in your question with the grey background?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem. I am getting more or less the exact same error.